# Unable to save model in Apache Spark -- Py4JJavaError

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We're getting an error while trying to save a model. model.save('DT')

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o822.save.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.```

Complete Error Stack --> http://dpaste.com/16Y07B9

Anything we missed here? It is creating the folder but not writing anything.

OS: Windows 10

TIA

Comment: `'kamlesh'` doesn't seem like a valid path

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I was using Spark 3.0.0Preview and ran into trouble. Switched to 2.4.5 and resolved it.